# Why is my flash drive saying "An operating system wasn't found. Try disconnecting any drives that don't contain an operating system."

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, usb-flash-drive, flash

I recently made my flash drive bootable but I was unsuccessful. I made it bootable through `diskpart` and did it with `power ISO`. Now, I want it to be back into normal but whenever I already inserted my flash drive into the port and I turn on my computer or restart it. It will say the following error.

> An operating system wasn't found. Try disconnecting any drives that
>   don't contain an operating system

How will I make my flash drive return to normal?
I am currently using Windows 10 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

- Start your computer and then connect your USB drive.
- Open Windows explorer (a.k.a My Computer) and see if the drive is
  shown.
- Right click on the USB icon and select format.

This will make your drive normal. (I'm assuming that you do not need any data from your USB drive - if you need any - you must back up before you format).

If this simple formatting does not help, try [low level format](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=low+level+formatting+of+usb&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-US:IE-Address&ie=&oe=&gfe_rd=cr&ei=y_fAWI_kFLK_-AP38ZiYBg). There are a lot of free tools to do this and most do not even require an installation of the program.